# Was Cleopatra technically a princess?

Tags: egypt

Obviously she eventually became pharaoh/queen, but as the daughter of the king was she technically a princess?

Comment: Does the term "princess" have a meaning in terms of Ptolemaic Egypt?

Comment: Thats kind of what im wondering.

Comment: @John then consider rephrasing the question to state that clearly.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Is this a question about what the English word the daughter of an Egyptian ruler is, what the Egyptian (or Greek) for that was, or a biographical question about her parentage and pre-rulership positions?

Comment: Yes its a question about what the english word for the daughter of an egyptian ruler is

Comment: Might want to make that explicit in the question.

Comment: Also, in that case the question is probably better for the English Language & Usage stack. The only one of the options I listed that is really OT here is the latter.

Comment: You might want to edit into your question that you are speaking of Cleopatra VII (as I assume that you are). Cleopatra I was a princess: she was the daughter of Antiochus the Great, and married to Ptolemy V. She lived a few hundred years before the Cleopatra who had a relationship with Mark Antony, and who died after (supposedly) being bitten by an asp.

Answer (score 6):

She was known as "s3t-niswt" which literally translates to Daughter of the King. "s3t-niswt" and "Princess" are similar but don't have the same meaning. "Princess" can be female close to the king including daughter-in-laws. "s3t-niswt" litterally means Daughter of the King and doesn't leave any ambiguity there.

Comment: You might want to edit into your answer which Cleopatra you (and the OP) are referring to.

Comment: s3t-niswt was a generic term used for any daughter of the king so there is no need for being specific. It can refer to Cleopatra II to the VII.